# how to delete columns with a certain count condition

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I'm trying to delete `id` that doesn't contain all 3 months in month.
For example, we have `df` as:

```
id       month   
100        1
100        2
100        3
101        2
102        3
```

Then I would like to have the new df as just with the `id` 100 like this:

```
id       month   
100        1
100        2
100        3
```

So what I've done is

```
df.groupby(['id'].month.count() == 3
```

which gives me

```
id        month
100        True
101        False
102        False
```

I'm currently stuck on how to continue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `groupby`+`transform('nunique')` and slice on the boolean output after comparison with `3`:

```
df[df.groupby('id')['month'].transform('nunique').eq(3)]
```

output:

```
    id  month
0  100      1
1  100      2
2  100      3
```

*NB. if you are sure there are no duplicated months, `transform('count')` will also work*

Answer (score 1):

I think you are close, but you need to modify your code a bit. Use your code but swap `count` with `nunique` which will return a `series` showing your ID's with `True` or  `False` depending whether they have all the months. Then, you can filter:

```
t = (df.groupby(['id']).month.nunique() == 3)
print(df.loc[df.id.isin(t[t].index)])

    id  month
0  100      1
1  100      2
2  100      3
```